# Angular form validation outside <form> tag

Tags: angularjs, angular-forms

This one is a silly question but is it possible, to get form status outside  block. Like,

```
<form name="form">
   <input type="text" name="name" required />
</form>

<button ng-disabled="form.$invalid"></button>
```

Because, button is outside form tag the status can't be acquired.
Do we have another way to achieve the same (may be using other language) ?

Comment: you just miss `ng-model` in your input becuse form name work as `$scope` in your html so you can use validation in all of your page, so add it in your input

Answer (score 1):

you can use form object anywhere in your controller scope, in my understanding angularJs bind form object to current ctrl scope, that's why we are able to use it, outer of form scope.
**here is demo**

```js
angular
 .module('app', [])
 .controller('ctrl', AppCtrl)
 
 function AppCtrl() {
    this.showFormInfo = function(form) {
    console.log(form);
    }
    
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as ct">
<form name="form" novalidate>
   <input type="text" name="test" ng-required="true" ng-model="name" />
   <span ng-if="">plz input</span>
   <button ng-click="ct.showFormInfo(form)">inside save</button>
</form>
<button ng-click="ct.showFormInfo(form)">outside save</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the answer I have posted to my own question is wrong at all.
After a lots of research I found the issue for my posted question.

Please have a look at this plunker, you will be getting better understanding.
https://plnkr.co/edit/IQ4eJ0NEM3rgWH2Atfh9?p=preview

Doesn't matter if,
 1. **name="name"** attribute,
 2. `<form name="form">`,
 3. or the form state you want is outside `<form>` tag.

The problem is `ng-if` condition that toggles your form.
you can use `ng-show` or `ng-hide` instead.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things.

1. Add **ng-model** to the input
2. call angular function using **ng-click** from the button.

Try this below code

```
<form name="form">
   <input type="text" name="test" ng--model="test" required />
</form>

<button ng-disabled="form.$invalid" ng-click="buttonClicked()"></button>
```

Now you can access the test inside buttonClicked() functions. Add this function in the controller.

Comment: Yes, I know that trick, without doing any extras, can I do same on html that angular provides?

Comment: Then try accessing the test variable by id. e.g.: getElementById('test'). I believe if you have a angularjs application, there is nothing wrong in using ng-model, ng-click to solve our purpose. But the decision is in your hand.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I get my answer on my own and it's really what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The question I have posted is really a good and may be useful for developers.
Actually angular preserves the form scope outside of it's  block too.

But never ever use **name="name"** attribute inside the form block.
otherwise the form will not be validated at all.

So, the answer is,
You can get the form state outside `<form>` block (May be only for Angular).